# Shall I use a an article before "lack of"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, definite-article

Which one is correct?

> We introduce the xx model, which exploits the lack of consistency.

Or,

> We introduce the xx model, which exploits lack of consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask me as a reader, both are grammatical and I just have to say that *"(a) lack of consistency"* stands for *generality*, and *"the lack" for specificity"* which is preferable in your sentence. But in the non-affirmative form "lack" is viewed as a mass noun such as:

"There was ***no lack** of amusement* at the theater."

Also, if you are using *"lack"* as a general  reference [for its meaning], you could point out that if in singular, it really depends on your writing style, interpretation, or even approach.